# Enlarge MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect For some margin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion, mkpolygon

I have some annotations presented on a map (somepoints)
the map zooms in or out to fit all points - see working code below.

```
MKPolygon *poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:somepoints count:i];
[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([poly boundingMapRect]) animated:NO];
```

**Q**: I would like to expand this poly just slightly to have some margins, how can I enlarge this Region?

Comment: Also note you don't have to use `setRegion` (which requires converting the `MKMapRect` to `MKCoordinateRegion`).  You can use `setVisibleMapRect` directly and apply padding: `[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:poly.boundingMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 100, 100, 100) animated:NO];`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can increase the span of the region in order to add some margin:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([poly boundingMapRect]);
region.span.latitudeDelta *= 1.2;   // Increase span by 20% to add some margin
region.span.longitudeDelta *= 1.2;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```